# How to convert cypher c to its unique k-digit representation in base 256?

Tags: c++, encryption, rsa, padding, gmp

I write a cpp program to encrypt a message with padding. I think it works all right but I got stuck in the part where I have to convert cypher c to it's unique k-digit representation in base 256. Is there a gmp function I could use? Basically I have to "x = x_(xLen-1) 256^(xLen-1) + x_(xLen-2) 256^(xLen-2) + ... + x_1 256 + x_0" as the link shows https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8017#section-4.1. Hereby my code.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <gmpxx.h>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <memory>
using namespace std;

//Encryt or  decrypt with RSA
mpz_class RSA(mpz_class m, mpz_class e,mpz_class N)
{
mpz_class rop;
mpz_powm(rop.get_mpz_t(), m.get_mpz_t(), e.get_mpz_t(), N.get_mpz_t());
return rop;
}
//Print string under byte form with bytes separated by space
void print_serialized(string s)
{
for(int i=0;i<(int)s.length();i++){
    if(i%8==0)
        cout<<" "<<s[i];
    else
        cout<<s[i];
}
}

// Fill byte wit0 leading 0's
string fill0(string x)
{
string y;
while((int)x.length()%8!=0)
{
    y='0';
    x=y+x;
    y="";
}
return x;
}
int main(const int argc, const char * const argv[])
{
if(argc!=4)
{
    cout<<"Usage [Message] [Exponent] [Modulus]";
    return -1;
}

const mpz_class m(argv[1]), e(argv[2]), N(argv[3]),c;
mpz_class n;
int mlen,k,PSlen,c1=0;

/*----------------------Encrypt----------------------------*/

mlen=(mpz_sizeinbase(m.get_mpz_t(), 2))/8;
if((mpz_sizeinbase(m.get_mpz_t(), 2))%8!=0)
    mlen=mlen+1;
k=(mpz_sizeinbase(N.get_mpz_t(), 2))/8;
if((mpz_sizeinbase(N.get_mpz_t(), 2))%8!=0)
    k=k+1;
PSlen=k-mlen-3;
if(mlen>k-11)
{
    cout<<"ERROR: Message too long";
    return -1;
}
string PS, buffer;
while(c1<PSlen||c1<8){
    n=0;
    while(n==0)
        n=rand()%256;
    //cout<<endl<<n<<" "<<n.get_str(2);
    if ((int)n.get_str(2).length()!=8)
        buffer=fill0(n.get_str(2));
    else buffer=n.get_str(2);
    PS=buffer+PS;
    c1++;
}
//generate EM = 0x00 || 0x02 || PS || 0x00
//length of EM will be 3bytes + PSlength bytes => calculate length of PS
string EM;
for(int i=0;i<14;i++){
   EM.push_back('0');
}
EM.push_back('1');
EM.push_back('0');

//EM  || PS || 0x00
EM=EM+PS;

for(int i=0;i<8;i++){
   EM.push_back('0');
}

//EM  || message
if ((int)m.get_str(2).length()!=8)
        buffer=fill0(m.get_str(2));
EM=EM+buffer;

//Convert the encoded message EM to an integer message representative m (see Section 4.2):
mpz_class m1(EM,2);

mpz_class cypher=RSA(m1,e,N),rop;
//I2OSP
mpz_class x_256=256;
mpz_pow_ui(rop.get_mpz_t(), x_256.get_mpz_t(), k);
if (cypher >= rop){
    cout<<"ERROR: Integer too large";
    return -1;
}
//Write the integer x in its unique xLen-digit representation in base 256
for(int i=0;i<k;i++){
   //Insert code here.........................
}

return 0;
}
```

Comment: Did you see [Integer Import and Export](https://gmplib.org/manual/Integer-Import-and-Export.html)?

Comment: Right, I forgot about it. I just have to import it into base 256 and then add how many leading 0 bytes I still need, right?

Comment: Sort of, base 256 is a byte.

Comment: I use now " void *r=NULL;
    size_t *countp = (size_t*) malloc(sizeof(size_t));
    
    mpz_export (r, countp, 1, sizeof(char), 1, 0, cypher.get_mpz_t());" but r stays 0. Why happens this?

Comment: > If rop is NULL in this case, no block is allocated, just NULL is returned.